# Python: Undo/Redo for Modal Mode

Tags: python

Is it possible to make Undo/Redo for Modal Mode?
For example in blender's Templates there is a modal test (Templates->Python->Modal Operator). It looks like this: http://pastebin.com/Vs1NteED

the operator makes selection of objects. Is it possible to make Undo/Redo for the Modal Mode to revert some modal operations?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve, you can try to add "bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}" to the modal operator... ?

Comment: It will undo entire modal mode. Just imagune, a user selected 10 objects in ModalMode and he wants to undo 3 last selected objects...

Comment: Hello @mifth did you ever find a solution to this? I'm working on a Modal Add-on and it would be a good time for me to add the Redo Last functionality.

Comment: Hello, yes I found one solution. I used it in nonmodal way. But it will work in modal. https://github.com/mifth/mifthtools/blob/eda836ab826dde3a45b60289ec00fc612e0bbd7b/blender/addons/2.7/mira_tools/mi_simple_extrude.py#L78 Here you can see line 78 which saves a state before undo. Then line 92 makes undo.